# Как стилизовать radio button?

Tags: css, radiobutton

Всем привет, делаю кастомные `radio button` и хочу реализовать две функции, но не знаю как: 1. При выборе какой-то `radio-button` внутри нее должен появляться кружок синего цвета и 2. Если добавляется класс `InputForm invalid`, то `все radio-buttons` должны залиться красным цветом (обводка остаться прежней). Пробовал вот так:

```
.gender-select input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

и так:

```
  .InputForm.invalid .gender-select label input[type="radio"] {
    border-color: red;
  }
```

результата ноль. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
      <form onSubmit={handleStep2Submit} className={`InputForm ${selectedGender ? '' : 'invalid'}`}>

        <div className="gender-select">
          <label htmlFor="male">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="male"
              name="gender"
              value="male"
              checked={selectedGender === "male"}
              onChange={handleGenderChange}
              required
            />
            Мужской
          </label>

          <label htmlFor="female">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="female"
              name="gender"
              value="female"
              checked={selectedGender === "female"}
              onChange={handleGenderChange}
              required
            />
            Женский
          </label>

          <label htmlFor="other">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="other"
              name="gender"
              value="other"
              checked={selectedGender === "other"}
              onChange={handleGenderChange}
              required
            />
            Другой
          </label>
        </div>
        </form>
        
        <button className="RegisterButton" type="submit">
          Далее
        </button>
      </form>
      
    )}
```

CSS:

```
.gender-select input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}


.gender-select label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gender-select label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #cddef3;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что вы пытаетесь залить фоном элемент, который сами и спрятали? Может всё-таки работать с теми элементами, которые принимают участие в стилизации (_точнее имитации_) радио-кнопок: `label` и псевдокласс `::before`

Answer (score 0):

Для кастомизации формы можно воспользоваться Bootstrap

На главной странице Bootstrap описаны способы кастомизации форм, благодаря которым можно подобрать необходимый вариант отображения.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

три способа, которыми я обычно пользуюсь

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 40px;
}

.label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.15;
}

.label:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.radio1 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.radio1:checked {
    background-color: blue;
    border: blue;
}

.radio2,
.radio3 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}

.radio2 + span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.radio2:checked + span {
    background-color: blue;
    border: blue;
}

.radio3 + label {
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.radio3 + label::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.radio3:checked + label::before {
    background-color: blue;
    border: blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="label label1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio1">
    <span>Первый вариант</span>
</label>
<label class="label label2">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio2">
    <span></span>
    <span>Второй вариант</span>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" class="radio3">
<label for="radio" class="label label3">
    <span>Третий вариант</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Какой в этом смысл, если я использую display: none; и стилизую их? Разница в том, что в моем случае я  отключаю отображение стандартных radio button`s и создаю свои, а в вашем скрываю только их дизайн и поверх свой рисую? Ну и опять-таки, я не знаю каким образом реализовать при InputForm invalid заливку красного цвета внутри кнопок.

Comment: @Dream, ну раз вы используете `display: none`, тогда зачем вы пытаетесь стилизовать `input`? Он УЖЕ с `display: none`! Если бы вы вместо использования псевдоэлемента использовали бы мой способ стилизации, то все работало бы. Еще можно было бы создать `span` после `input'a` и стилизовать его, а когда `input` был бы `checked`, накидывать стили на `span` через селектор `+`

Comment: я попробовал Ваш способ, однако все равно у меня не получилось. В чем причина? .InputForm .gender-select input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before { /*Пробовал и без + label::before
  background-color: blue; /* Изменяем цвет кружка */
}

Comment: `input` не может обратится к `label` через `+`. `label` - родительский элемент. у вас получится с псевдоэлементом `label` работать только если вы поставите `input` перед  `label` и свяжите их с помощью `for` и `id`. Ща я сделаю ответ

Comment: @ Meth0d, спасибо большое, я немного подкорректировал Ваш код под себя и он работает. Но у меня вопрос, а как заставить вместо заливки внутри появляться кружок? Я пробовал вот так, но кружки добавлялись для всех радио кнопок: .GenderForm input[type="radio"]:checked ::after{/* стили круга */}.

Comment: @Dream, у `input` нет псевдоэлемента. можно взять картинку синего кружка и поставить бэкграундом с `background-size: 16px;`, например. У меня обычно весь кружок заливается, а внутри бэкграундом белая галочка. Со спаном такой проблемы не будет, там можно псевдоэлемент засовывать